# Proguard Printmapping not working in Android Studio 2.0.0 (and 2.1.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, android-studio-2.0

Using gradle wrapper 2.10, and Android Gradle build tools <strike>2.0.0-beta7</strike> **2.1.0**

From my build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        all{
            minifyEnabled  true
            proguardFiles = [getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), 'proguard-project.pro'];
        }
    }
```

This works. Things are obfuscated.

I have the following line in my proguard-project.pro as well:

`-printmapping my-mapping.txt`

Everything else in that file works fine, but the mapping keeps getting printed to the wrong place:

`Printing mapping to [C:\path\to\my\project\build\outputs\mapping\debug\mapping.txt]`

Has this syntax changed?

Note: I've tried supplying a direct path. I've tried supplying a name without a hyphen. Nothing changes.

For now I just made a gradle copy task for it.

Comment: What do you mean, Wrong place?

Comment: @RaGe In the past, that line would put the mapping file in the project root. 

Now, regardless of where that line points, it always prints the mapping in the build folder AND with the wrong name,

Comment: I'm not familiar with what it was in the past, but if you want to put it in a specific folder, you should try providing an absolute path. As for wrong name, maybe the hyphen in the file name is an issue? Try enclosing it in quotes.

Comment: I've done all of that, it doesn't change.

Comment: what about -basedirectory directoryname
(In your proguard.pro file.  Specifies the base directory for all subsequent relative file names in these configuration arguments or this configuration file.) ?

Comment: -printmapping  in section "obfuscation options" is what you want. Provide a filespec to it and no more copy task needed..http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html..see gradle task then look for print mapping

Comment: @RobertRowntree the issue is that the printmapping function is not working...

Answer (score 11):

The mapping file at location `build\outputs\mapping\debug\mapping.txt` is the default one that gets generated even when you don't specify `-printmapping my-mapping.txt` inside `proguard-project.pro`. I see the name is always `mapping.txt` so  `-printmapping` is being ignored with the new Android Studio version.

I remember it used to get generated at the same project root folder where `proguard-project.pro` is present but I confirm, it doesn't generate now with Android Studio 2.0 and is a bug that you can file at [Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

---

UPDATE

Link to Android Issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205213

Comment: It would seem that someone just filed it. Could you update the link to point here? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205213

Answer (score 4):

Faced with same problem, but it seems that

```
{projectRoot}\build\outputs\mapping\debug\mapping.txt
```

is correct place for mapping files now

Comment: I feel like the method is simply broken. Why would the build pass with printmapping in it if it's not meant to work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change to follwoing

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')，'some-other-rules.txt'
            //proguardFile 'some-other-rules.txt' 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android Studio 3.5.3 and AGP 3.5.3 the `-printmapping` parameter is respected.

For example using:

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

It is copied from the default:

`{projectRoot}\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt`

to:

`{projectRoot}\mapping.txt`

Answer (score -1):

Just try to start Android Studio as administrator.

```
-printmapping
```

may not write to system folder which cause this issue.